# How to locate a point on google map by passing latitude and longitude in android app

Tags: android, api, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am a newbie in android programming, I have a set of latitude and longitude coming from API, I want to show the location corresponding to that latitude and longitude on google map, I tried searching through google but did not found any suitable link. Please help.

Comment: try this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward. You can use Marker for this, try below code,

```
float myLatitude = <some value>
float myLogitude = <some value>


 GoogleMap map = //initiate your map
 Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLogitude))
        .title("Location Name"));
 map.add(marker);
```

For more info check this link
[SampleCode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker)

Answer (score 0):

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourLat, yourLon)
                .title("Marker title"));